# Good resource to practice C++ Arrays and Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm learning C++ from book. I think I understand basic concept but the book provide not much exercise. I want to know website, opensource project or any resource that provice exercise or souce code that I can read and get my hand dirty with C++ Arrays and Pointers.

Comment: What did you find when you googled this question? That is, how many thousands of references? I'm just curious.

Comment: if you program in C++ my advice is: don't use arrays and pointers. You need to understand their dangereousness and limitations.

Comment: @wiso I think due to these comlications only the OP wants to practice questions on them.Moreover I don't think there is any disadvantage of using arrays in C++ as compared to C.

Comment: @Pete I found lots of result when I google with "C++ arrays and pointer" but all of them is about basic concept/example. I'm looking for things that more advance.

Comment: I don't know what you're hoping to find in the "more advanced" section. Skilled programmers **avoid** that stuff as much as possible, and for good reason: the necessary library-building work was done a long, long time ago, in pretty much every case.

Comment: @Karl Do you mean it's rarely use array and pointer in modern C++ programming? If so, does it OK to know only basic concept and stick with vector and string whenever posible?

Comment: Vector and string are obfuscated classes- they are a specific implementation using array and pointer. Learn the basics first if you plan to look at many legacy articles/questions/solutions.

Comment: You need to know the basics first to later decide what implementation of standard library is good for you and what isn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is conceptually no difference between C and C++ when it comes to pointers and arrays.Practice K&R questions. They are good and comprehensive. 
The theory provided in it is good enough to get you started with complex logic related to pointers and arrays.

Comment: Do you have link to K&R question?

Comment: No. You can have a look at http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/ for further references.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing and dereferencing are the bread and butter of C++ (and C) developers. It is often said that any problem is solvable given sufficient levels of indirection. This is taken to its logical conclusion in managed languages which treat objects as references by default but without the finer grained control of an unmanaged language like C or C++. Managed languages overhead is partly due to this default, maximum indirection, but mostly due to Garbage Collection, which is why indirection is such a boon to more efficient solutions.

Have a look at machine instructions or assembly code to appreciate the power and scope of pointers.

As for arrays, it has been my experience that pointers are the best way to pass these around. Had I more patience I might discover that arrays are passed as references also, and equally efficient as parameters, but C doesn't employ such non standard deviations from expected behaviour and is what I cut my teeth on in the C/Java/C++/C# family of languages.

Also arrays are pretty much limited to static sizing, whereas pointers are not. I saw a question about C99 arrays last night that indicated dynamic arrays were part of that standard but I'd have to be cautious regarding just how dynamic they are. It is often tricky to get the initialization (I mean size definition) performed at the right time without using a variable to define the array size- this was what the C99 question identified, a variable in that initialization.

Sorry for lack of links, I've observed here before that they might be described as poor for an answer.

Comment: It is great for lower level, finer grained solutions, but I use C++-CLI and .NET for practical Windows apps.